# Extracting summaries from multiple data frames

Tags: r, function

Alright, this should be a fairly straightforward task but I'm having trouble.

Let's say I have a group of 50 data frames in my library. For example's sake, let's say each data frame contains information for each US state, its population, tax revenue, and unemployment rate.

I want to create a new data frame which makes a table of the summary of tax revenue for each state.

The approach I tried was creating a vector of the data frames

```
data <- c(New.York,Virginia,Maryland)
```

then creating a function that reads in that vector and summarizes the tax variable (so `Virginia$tax`, etc.) for each element of the vector (each element being the state data frame) and appends it to a table.

The problem I'm having is that when I refer to each element of the vector

```
for (i in data){
    print (i$cost)
}
```

R doesn't recognize that element as a dataframe. It says:

```
Error in i$cost : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Does anybody have a more straightforward way of doing creating a table of summaries from other data frames?

Comment: Since there -already- are answers, I'll just add that when you `c` your data frames you -just- get a list where each element is a column from all the data frames. Instead, you could `list` them and proceed with your code or, even beeter, as suggested in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of remarks concerning your code:

1. The `$` operator is a handy operator to be used esstially in the
   interactive mode. Better to use `[` or `[[` inside a function or a
   loop.
2. The R-way to loop through a  list is to use `XXapply` (`lapply`, `sapply`). This will avoid the possible side effect of using `for` and also avoid pre-allocating memory.

Here an example using `sapply` , but first I create a reproducible example( since you don't provide one):

```
set.seed(1)
ll <- replicate(3, data.frame(tax= rnorm(1),
                  population=rnorm(1,10)),simplify=FALSE)
ll <- setNames(ll,c('New.York','Virginia','Maryland'))
```

Then to get tax's vector:

```
sapply(ll,'[[','tax')
 New.York   Virginia   Maryland 
-0.6264538 -0.8356286  0.3295078
```

or using `lapply` to get  population summary:

```
lapply(ll,'[[','population')

$New.York
[1] 10.18364

$Virginia
[1] 11.59528

$Maryland
[1] 9.179532
```

Comment: agstudy, thank you very much -- this was very helpful. In addition to the original question, I should mention that each data frame has a a couple hundred observations, so I was ultimately looking for a way to get quick summaries of some numeric variable that's common across all of them (min, med, max, etc.). But it looks like using summary(sapply(ll,'[[','tax')) does the trick here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
    mydata1<-mtcars[1:10,1:2]
    mydata2<-mtcars[11:20,1:2]
    mydata<-list(mydata1,mydata2)
   for (i in mydata){show(i[,"mpg"])}


     [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2
 [1] 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9
```